# how to add MeshGeometry3D dynamically to Helixviewport

Tags: sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I want add MeshGeometry3D dynamically to Helixviewport.

I am having multiple MeshGeometry3D . Now I want to append multiple MeshGeometry3D dynamically to Helixviewport (HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX). I tried many methods , but I cant achieve it!!!!!!!

I have tried with Modelvisual3d.children.append(),helixviewport.children.append() but I cant achieve it

USING LIBRARIES(HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX)

Comment: You can't mix Helix toolkit wpf and sharpdx objects. They are completely separate libraries.

Comment: I'm sorry , that i didnt mention it correctly .I am using  HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX libraries .In this   HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX , i want to show how meshes are creating by lively ....

Comment: Modelvisual3d is from wpf. You need to use viewport3dx with models from Helix toolkit.Wpf.Sharpdx. Please follow some of the examples from Helix toolkit repo on GitHub.